# Ethernet speed at 2.5Gbps despite interface being 5Gbps and negotiated as such

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I'm having a weird problem. I have a desktop computer with an Aquantia 5Gbps interface (`Aquantia Corp. AQC111 NBase-T/IEEE 802.3bz Ethernet Controller [AQtion] (rev 02)`) connected to a Mikrotik 10Gbps switch (`Mikrotik CRS312-4C+8XG-RM`) and that connected to a Dell R720 with a 10Gbps NIC.

The thing is, in my computer (running Linux 6.2.2) the network interface is negotiated correctly at 5Gbps full duplex, but for some reason download speeds are capped at 2.5Gbps. I looked into the Aquantia Atlantic drivers but it seems that it's discouraged to use them on Linux 6.2 since they are already integrated.

I fear that the link negotiation is not working as expected, but I'm a bit over my head on this one, can anyone give me hints of that could be wrong here?

TL;DR: Computer with 5Gb NIC connected to 10Gb switch and server with 10Gb NIC also connected to the switch, I only get 2.5Gbps speeds despite being negotiated at 5Gbps.

Update: @Peregrino69 suggested running iperf3. The results hsow that there is no issue at network level, according to the results, but for some reason copying files is capped still (I tried a 240GB single-file copy). Any other ideas why this could be happening?

```
    Connecting to host XX.XX.XX.XX, port 5201
[  5] local XX.XX.XX.XX port 48272 connected to XX.XX.XX.XX port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   564 MBytes  4.73 Gbits/sec    0   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   560 MBytes  4.70 Gbits/sec    8   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec   25   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.31 MBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.32 MBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   561 MBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec    0   1.32 MBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  5.48 GBytes  4.71 Gbits/sec   33             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  5.48 GBytes  4.69 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Install `iperf3` on both the server and the desktop. Run iperf server on the server `iperf3 -s`, and client on the desktop `iperf3 -c <server IP address>` to run quick basic test. `iperf` is pretty much industry standard tool for measuring throughput. Here's [Techmint's iperf3 tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/test-network-throughput-in-linux/). `iperf3 -h` shows you all available options.

Comment: @Peregrino69 thanks! I performed the test and everything seems fine (I updated the post with the results), but after that I tried another file copy (240GB single file) and it's still limited to 250MB/s. I don't know if it is my file browsers faults or something else to be honest.

Comment: Do you get better download speeds on the other devices?

Comment: @harrymc my desktop is the only device with >1Gbps interface for now to be honest. I still need to upgrade the rest of the machines. The rest work at 1Gbps no problem.

Comment: That's the point of the test :-) Now you know the problem's somewhere in OS/application level. Trying different transfer methods and tools is likely to eventually lead to the culprit.

Comment: @CastleDweller please specify 250MB/s or 2.5GB/s? Is there a zero missing? Could you add a network schematic? How many ports capable of >1GB do you have in total (on the client and server)? What kind of cables do you use?

Comment: @Albin I mentioned 2.5Gbps (not the same as 2.5GB, 2.5Gbps~=250MB/s). Cables are Cat7 for the whole infra. Deskop goes to patch panel->microkit 10Gbps. Server goes directly to the mikrotik. Only my desktop and the server are >1Gbps, server is 10Gb, desktop is 5Gb.

Comment: @CastleDweller 2.5Gbps~=250MB can't be correct, there's a factor of 10 missing... and you didn't answer my question: how many network ports above 1GB does the server have, how many does the client have? Do you use patch cables?

Comment: @Albin: 'b' versus 'B' is the factor of 10. (Yes, technically 1B=8b, but I usually see bits/sec being used for raw transfer with the ~10% IP/TCP overhead included and bytes/sec for useful transfer, at which point it becomes closer to 10x than 8x (i.e. 2.5 Gbps of "raw" throughput ≈ 250 MB/s of "useful" data transfer).

Comment: @Albin I already found the issue, but I'm going to tell you. The desktop has 1x2.5Gbps (disconnected) and 1x5Gbps ports, the 5Gbps port connected to a Cat6A patch panel via Cat7 cable, from there to the Mikrotik switch. The server has 2x10Gbps ports and 2x1Gbps ports, only one 10Gbps port is connected and it goes directly to the Mikrotik switch.

Comment: Never mind then, I was just asking for testing purposes. Might I suggest using the same reference frame when talking about numbers in the future? It makes it much easier for the reader.

Comment: @Albin yes, sorry if my way of writing it caused some confusion. Even if I'm familiar with all this stuff I'm still learning so I'm prone to making mistakes :)

Comment: For future reference - if you suspect a network, especially negotiation, issue, you do need to state the model of transceiver used - especially for NBASE-T, as it's relatively new and can be an issue.

Comment: @Albin it shouldn't really need calling out that 1Gbps Ethernet means file transfers well under 128 MBps, and so 2Gbps means <256 MBps. Anyone who's dealt with the subject is well aware of this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was caused by a factor (disk performance) which is unrelated to the topic of the question (network performance).

Comment: @NickMatteo That wasn't my point... I wasn't taking about "networking" I was talking about "writing". If you start out writhing about Gbps stick to Gbps and don't change the reference frame to Mbps or mbps or MBps or whatever. This makes it unnecessarily complicated. "Anyone who's dealt with the subject is well aware of this" (which is an absolutely unnecessary and presumptuous sentence when being used to close an argument...  you get my drift).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I don't think this is a good reason to close the question, because the cause wasn't known when the question was posed, and "your network problem might not be a network problem after all" is quite common. (If I had a penny for every time a HTTPS transfer was slower than the link speed because the CPU couldn't en/decrypt fast enough)...  This is superuser, not networking, so the question should be on topic even when the cause is hard disks, not networks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I finally found the issue. It seems that I misconfigured my disks in TrueNAS and I wasn't using the NVMe cache drive. It was hitting directly the HDs (IronWolf Pro, write rate ~250MB/s) instead of going to the NVMe first. As I said, I'm a bit over my head hehe.

Thanks everyone for all the pointers! they have been really helpful :)

Comment: "my LAN is faster than my spinning hard drive"  That's a technology milestone.... I remember reaching "my internet is faster than a floppy read" and "inet faster than a CDROM"

Comment: Ahh dem Good 'Ol Days :-D

Comment: Kids today. I remember when my kettle boiled in less time than it took to entirely fill my first computers' 3853 bytes of RAM from cassette. Loading screens would say "Go make a cup of tea" and meant it.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru, I remember typing my first program out of a magazine, switching the computer off after being satisfied, and then heading out to buy a datasette after I learned about storing stuff, the next day.

Comment: The good old days, when you could type faster than your modem could transmit.

Comment: At some point my home internet became faster than the home local network (coax Ethernet).